# I need to get the amount of numbers entered from a parameter and assign them to variables

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am making a program that will have the user provide a 3 digit number when running the program. If it does not have 3 numbers, then Im to give an error message. How can I test the length of the number and also how can I assign each number out of those digits to a variable?

Thanks for any help in advance!

I tried doing: `grep '^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$'` but that did not work.

Comment: You seem to have changed your question considerably...  If you want to test if a directory exists, use `test`, or `[`, or `[[` 

[ -d /numbers ] && echo "dir exists"

be careful with editing your original post, it makes it confusing for other people later

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @user3524591. Please confine your question to one question, and if you have another question, ask it in a second post.

Comment: @kojiro : I don't want to delete the answer... It seem to work for most of the cases... you are one of the voters...  you could at least nullify yours if it is ok with you... I can leave with one down vote for today..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following as a starting point. Add more error checking for getting practice.

```
#!/bin/bash

while : 
do
    read -p "Enter a three digit number or q to quit: " input
    if (( input >= 100 && input <= 999)); then 
        echo "good entry"
        digit1=${input:0:1} && echo "digit1 is $digit1"
        digit2=${input:1:1} && echo "digit2 is $digit2"
        digit3=${input:2:1} && echo "digit3 is $digit3"
    elif [[ $input == "q" ]]; then
        break
    else
        echo "bad entry"
    fi
done
```

#### Output:

```
Enter a three digit number or q to quit: 4256
bad entry
Enter a three digit number or q to quit: 242
good entry
digit1 is 2
digit2 is 4
digit3 is 2
Enter a three digit number or q to quit: 562
good entry
digit1 is 5
digit2 is 6
digit3 is 2
Enter a three digit number or q to quit: q
###program breaks here
```

Comment: could yo have a look at my added info in my question. Im having trouble with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want a variable for each number in the user submission?

ie - foo_one = 1, foo_two = 2, foo_three = 3  ?

Or do you just want to iterate them and "do something" with each one?

Here's something I just threw together that might help you on the right track:

```
#!/bin/bash

die() { printf "%s\n" "$@" 1>&2; exit 1; }

read -p "Enter 3 digit number " num

if [[ "${#num}" -lt 3 ]]; then
        die "Error: Please enter at least 3 digits."
else
        for (( i=0; i<${#num}; i++ )); do
                echo " var $i is ${num:$i:1}"
        done
fi
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ ./sotest.sh
Enter 3 digit number 123
var 0 is 1
var 1 is 2
var 2 is 3
```

Sorry if this doesn't help.  Maybe you can provide some more info on the overall goal?

Comment: Consider having `die` output to standard error?

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

userInput=$1

if [ $(grep -o "[0-9]" <<< $userInput | wc -l) -ne 3 ] || \
    [ $(grep -o "[a-z]" <<< $userInput | wc -l) -gt 0 ] || \
    [ $(grep -o "[A-Z]" <<< $userInput | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then 
   echo "Provide exactly a 3-digit number. No letters, just Numbers..."; 
   exit 1;
else
   digi1=$(grep -o "[0-9]" <<< $userInput | awk 'NR==1{print}');
   digi2=$(grep -o "[0-9]" <<< $userInput | awk 'NR==2{print}');
   digi3=$(grep -o "[0-9]" <<< $userInput | awk 'NR==3{print}');

   echo "Digit-1 is $digi1";
   echo "Digit-2 is $digi2";
   echo "Digit-3 is $digi3";
fi
```

Output :

```
]$  ./test.bash 134
   Digit-1 is 1
   Digit-2 is 3
   Digit-3 is 4
```

Comment: this works, but if the user enters a number less than 3 numbers it doesnt output the message and gives an exit status of 0

Comment: This is not a good answer.  I'm not a Bash purist (nor am I that skilled with Bash / other shells), but this makes me cringe, when there are so many other better ways to do something so simple.  I thought the problem was more nuanced.  User input sanitization seemed to be a secondary concern anyway..  Oh well.